Drag Items from QListWidget and drop it to the QTableWidget in pyQT
I have a QListWidget and a QTableWidget in my main window. I need to drag an element from the QListWidget and place it in the QTableWidget as a row or column (depends on whether the event will be triggered from the vertical or horizontal header).
But I can't customize dropEvent on headers: dragging the item "Item 1" into the table between rows 2 and 3 should add the new row named "Item 1".

I've tried to customize event in the QTableWidget, but it works only for cells:
class customTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Set Style
        self.setStyleSheet(tableStyle)
        # ScrollBars
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
         # Allow to drop elements
        # self.setDragEnabled(True)
        # self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        # self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        # self.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)


        # Allow to replace rows and columns in the table        
        self.verticalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)

        # verticalHeader Drop
        self.verticalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
        self.verticalHeader().setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.verticalHeader().setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)
        # horizontalHeader Drop
        self.horizontalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
        self.horizontalHeader().setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.horizontalHeader().setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)
      

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'):
            data = event.mimeData()
            source_item = QStandardItemModel()
            source_item.dropMimeData(data, Qt.CopyAction, 0,0, QModelIndex())
            print(source_item.item(0, 0).text())

Any suggestions on how to get this desired behavior?
Code without custom table:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QAbstractItemView, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QListWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

tableStyle =    '''
                QTableWidget::item {background-color: "#F4FAFB";
                border-style: outset;
                border-width:1px; border-radius: 2px; border-color: #AEAEAE}
                QTableWidget::item:selected {background-color: #66C3D0;
                border-width:1px; border-radius: 2px; color: white; border-color: #333333}               
                '''
  


class TableDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a ListWidget
        self.list = QListWidget(self)
        self.list.addItem('Item 1')
        self.list.addItem('Item 3')
        self.list.addItem('Item 4')

        # Set Drag and Drop
        self.list.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)

        # Create a QTableWidget
        self.table = QTableWidget(self)

        # # Set Style
        self.table.setStyleSheet(tableStyle)

        # Set number of rows and columns
        self.table.setRowCount(5)
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)

        # Set headers
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'])
        self.table.setVerticalHeaderLabels(['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4', 'Row 5'])

        # ScrollBars
        self.table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.table.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        # Allow to replace rows and columns in the table        
        self.table.verticalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)

        # Customize Drop Event
        self.table.verticalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
        # self.table.verticalHeader().setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
        # self.table.horizontalHeader().setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)


        # Populate the table with data
        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(3):
                self.table.setItem(row, col, QTableWidgetItem(f"Item ({row+1}, {col+1})"))
                # self.table.item(row,col).setText('New text')
                # self.table.item(row, col).setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDropEnabled)

        # Layout setup
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.list)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Window properties
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget Demo")
        self.resize(800, 300)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TableDemo()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Scroll areas (widgets inheriting from QAbstractScrollArea, including item views) only provide some overrides for the viewport events, including drag and drop. Either subclass the headers, or override event() of the table and check for DragEnter, DragMove and Drop events, eventually mapping the event coordinates to the header.

It looks like I've started to figure out how to do what I need to do.
Added the following lines to the "customTable" class:
        # Custom headers
    HH = customQHeaderView(parent = self, orientation=Qt.Horizontal)
    VH = customQHeaderView(parent = self, orientation=Qt.Vertical)

    self.setHorizontalHeader(HH)
    self.setVerticalHeader(VH)

And added new class "customQHeaderView":
class customQHeaderView(QHeaderView):
MimeType = 'application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'

def __init__(self, orientation: Qt.Orientation, parent=None):
    super().__init__(orientation, parent)
    self.setDragEnabled(True)
    self.setAcceptDrops(True)

def dropEvent(self, event):
    mimedata = event.mimeData()
    if mimedata.hasFormat(customQHeaderView.MimeType):
        if event.source() is not self:
            source_item = QStandardItemModel()
            source_item.dropMimeData(mimedata, Qt.CopyAction, 0,0, QModelIndex())
            label = source_item.item(0, 0).text()
            print(label)
            event.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
    else:
        super().dropEvent(event)

